# Counting no.of bodies present in certain area in box2d?

Tags: box2d

I am stuck on it:how can i count or find the no.of bodies present in any area in as3?would be thankful if any guys help me out.....

Comment: Box2D must have some sort of spatial partitioning, such as a quadtree.  You should be able to query that partitioning to determine what objects are inside of a selection.

Answer (score 1):

Create a fixture which has the exact size as the desired area, set the fixture's sensor property to true and check the number of collisions which include the sensor fixture.

You can find more about sensor fixtures in the [official box2d documentation](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972)